# Limit of $F_{n}(\lfloor{nx}\rfloor)$ where $ F_{n}(k)=G_{n}(k)+H_{n}(k)F_{n}(k-1) $ and $F_{n}(0)=\mu_n.$

Tags: sequences-and-series, recurrence-relations, recursion

The following conjecture is inspired by asymptotic results in generalizations of the secretary problem.

CONJECTURE
Consider a sequence of functions {$F_n$} with $F_{n}:[0,n]\cap
\mathbb{Z}\rightarrow\mathbb{R}$ defined recursively, for $k\in \{1,\ldots,n\}$, by:
$$F_{n}(k)=G_{n}(k)+H_{n}(k)F_{n}(k-1)\text{ and }F_{n}(0)=\mu_n \rightarrow \mu.$$

with $|H_n(k)|< 1$ and $|G_n(k)|<M$ for all $(n,k)$

Let $f_{n}(x):=F_{n}(\lfloor{nx}\rfloor)$, $h_{n}(x):=n(1-H_{n}(\lfloor
{nx}\rfloor))$ and $g_{n}(x):=nG_{n}(\lfloor{nx}\rfloor)$. If both $h_{n}(x)$
and $g_{n}(x)$ converge in $(0,1)$ and uniformly in $[\varepsilon
,\varepsilon^{\prime}]$ for all $0<\varepsilon<\varepsilon^{\prime}<1$ to
continuous functions in $(0,1)$, $h(x)$ and $g(x)$, respectively, then
$f_{n}(x)\rightarrow f(x)$ uniformly in $[\varepsilon
,\varepsilon^{\prime}]$ for all $0<\varepsilon<\varepsilon^{\prime}<1$ with $f\in \mathcal{C}^1(0,1)$ and $f$ satisfies the following differential equation in $(0,1)$
$$f^{\prime}(x)= -f(x)h(x)+g(x).$$

Example :

$$F_{n}(k)=\frac{1}{n}+\frac{n-k}{n-k+1}F_{n}(k-1)\text{ and }F_{n}(0)=0.$$
$$F_{n}(\lfloor{nx}\rfloor) \rightarrow (x-1) \log(1-x) $$
The associated differential equation is:
$$1-\frac{f(x)}{1-x}=f'(x)$$

(1) Ribas, J.M.G. A new look at the returning secretary problem. J Comb Optim 37, 1216–1236 (2019). https://doi.org/10.1007/s10878-018-0349-8

(2) Bayón, L., Fortuny Ayuso, P., Grau, J.M. et al. A New Method for Computing Asymptotic Results in Optimal Stopping Problems. Bull. Malays. Math. Sci. Soc. 46, 46 (2023). https://doi.org/10.1007/s40840-022-01436-4

Answer (score 4):

Unfortunately, similarly to the situation with your other [question](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/463221/limit-of-f-n-lfloornx-rfloor-where-f-nk-g-nkh-nkf-nk1),
the uniform convergence in $[\varepsilon,\varepsilon^{\prime}]$ for all $0<\varepsilon<\varepsilon^{\prime}<1$ is a too weak condition for the conclusion.
For instance, let $\mu\ne 0$, $M>1$, for each natural $n$ pick $\varepsilon_n>0$ such that $(1-\varepsilon_n)^n\ge 1-\frac 1{n^2}$, and for each natural $k<n$ put $G_n(k)=0$ and $H_n(k)=1-\varepsilon_n$, but the case $H_n(1)=\left(\frac 12+\frac {(-1)^n}4\right) 
(1-\varepsilon_n)$. Then $F_n(k)=H_n(1)\mu_n(1-\varepsilon_n)^{k-1}$ when $k\ge 2$. Thus both $h_{n}(x)$ and $g_{n}(x)$ converge in $(0,1)$ and uniformly in $[\varepsilon,\varepsilon^{\prime}]$ for all $0<\varepsilon<\varepsilon^{\prime}<1$ to the zero function, but even the sequence $(f_n(1/2))_{n\in\mathbb N}$ diverges.

Comment: OK, Okay. Thank you. I just changed to |H_n(k)| < 1

Comment: @GrauRibas This does not help, see the modified answer.

Comment: OK. and ....0<H_n(k)< 1

Comment: @GrauRibas See the next modification of the answer.

Comment: New hypothesis: For all $k$ exists $\lim_{n->\infty} H_n(k)$ and $\lim_{n->\infty} G_n(k)$

Comment: @GrauRibas It does not work either. To see this we change the exclusive term from  $H_n(1)$ to $H_n(\lfloor\sqrt{n}\rfloor)$.

Comment: $ \bullet$ $  H_n(k)   \rightarrow \mathcal{H}(k)$ uniformly; i.e. for all $\epsilon>0$ exists $n_\epsilon$ such that $$n>n_\epsilon \Rightarrow | H_n(k)-\mathcal{H}(k)|<\epsilon,\textrm{ for all }k$$

$ \bullet$ $  G_n(k)   \rightarrow \mathcal{G}(k)$ uniformly. $$ $$

$ \bullet$ Considering: $ \mathcal{F}(0)=\mu$ and $\mathcal{F}(k):=\mathcal{G}(k)+ \mathcal{H}(k) \mathcal{F}(k-1)$, exists $\mathfrak{L}:=\lim_{k\rightarrow \infty}\mathcal{F}(k)$.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/151528/discussion-between-grau-ribas-and-alex-ravsky).